# How do I pass a json object from one function to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps

I have a jquery function which via a php file, retrieves latitude and longitude from a database. In the same js file, I have a function that places markers on a Google map. I want to use the json(lat and long) returned by the first function, in the Google maps add marker function. Currently in my code below, ..the json data is simply displayed in an empty div.  Is there some way to access that json data between functions, or can I combine the two functions somehow?

```
        // Google Map

    var map;

    // markers for map
    var markers = [];

    // initialize the map
    function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: 37.09024, lng: -95.712891},
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 
        zoom: 4
      });
    }



    // add markers 
    function addMarker(data) {     
      // get lat and long from data(json object)      
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(data.latitude), parseFloat(data.longitude));
      // custom marker image
      //var image = "../img/infoblue.png"; 
      // new marker
      var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,  
        labelClass: "label",
        labelContent: data.name,
        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(20,0),    
      });

      // add marker to array
      markers.push(marker);  
    } 

// this function gets json and then displays in a div on an html page   
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.airport_form').submit(function(){

            // show that something is loading
            $('#response').html("<b>Loading response...</b>");

          $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "response.php",
            data: $(this).serialize()
            })
            .done(function(data){

              // show the response
              $('#response').html("Name -> " + data.name + "<br>" + " Iata code -> " + data.iata + "<br>" + " Lat. -> " + data.latitude + "<br>" + " Longitude -> " + data.longitude);

            })
            .fail(function() {

                // just in case posting the form fails
                alert( "Posting failed." );

            });
      // to prevent refreshing the whole page page 
      return false;
      });
    });
```

Comment: Once an object has been parsed from wire-format JSON, it's not a "JSON Object" - it's a plain old JavaScript object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add your `addMarker` function to your `done` function like so ...

```
           .done(function(data){
              // add marker from data
              addMarker(data);

              // show the response
              $('#response').html("Name -> " + data.name + "<br>" + " Iata code -> " + data.iata + "<br>" + " Lat. -> " + data.latitude + "<br>" + " Longitude -> " + data.longitude);

            })
```

Comment: Thank you..the answers always seem to be so simple once you get them!